# how to show different letters in textfield when clicking different buttons of keyboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard, uikeyinput

I am doing a keyboard by calling UIView and I have many buttons with different letters. I don't know how to get different letters in textfield because when I touch different button, it show the same letter in textfield. what is the code for telling that user touches the different button ?

Comment: What is the code that you have there now? It nearly works, so it would probably be easier to fix than to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the buttons should call the same IBAction.

Mine is called "-(IBAction)addCharacter:(id)sender".

Then you just do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)addCharacter:(id)sender
{
    //you can send an UIButton directly too.
    UIButton *charBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonPressed = charBtn.currentTitle.
    //Your UITextField gets modified here.
    //This method will append whatever button is pressed at the end of the string.
    someTextField.text = [someTextField.text stringByAppendingString:buttonPressed];
}
```

That's the basics. Obviously if your keyboard needs to remove the last character, you will need to modify, but it should be easy to do using this base code.

Comment: do you know how to customize keyboard in iphone without using button like this?